# "se han bloqueado algunas imágenes para evitar que el remitente identifique su equipo"

Tags: email, img, src

Buen día, como podría solucionar esto "se han bloqueado algunas imágenes para evitar que el remitente identifique su equipo" el punto es que quiero que agregar una firma a un correo de windows live mail y pues se tiene que agregar una imagen en un archivo de html pero cuando abro el archivo de html no me aparece la imagen

Según yo esta bien porque ya lo probé en 2 maquinas y si funciona
[image]

pero lo pruebo en la maquina que le quiero agregar la firma al correo y no me reconoce las imagenes y ya las puse en la misma carpeta las imagenes y aun asi no reconoce las imágenes

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En donde estas abriendo eso? le falta contexto a esta pregunta...

Comment: lo estoy abriendo desde bloc de notas para ver mis posibles errores pero aun asi no me carga la imagen :(

Comment: La _"maquina que le quiero agregar la firma al correo"_ ¿Tiene esa ruta absoluta? Las rutas absolutas como `src` son MUY pero MUY mala idea SIEMPRE. Cambias el nombre a una carpeta y se rompen completamente. Sin contar que solo sirven en tu computadora, no tienen portabilidad alguna.

Comment: si bro, mira cuando paso el archivo a ese equipo ubico la imagen en el mismo lugar para que la reconozca y ni aun asi :(

Comment: Este problema ya lo he tenido en la empresa. Si la ruta de la imagen está relativa, no se adjunta en el correo. Y si está en una ubicación remota, entonces el cliente de correo la bloquea. Me ha funcionado así como coloqué en la respuesta. Pero también dependerá del cliente (que no especificas), en thunderbird o wlm funciona, pero no en MS Outlook ya que lo trabaja con html embebido en la configuración.

Comment: si bro, bueno es de una cuenta de windows live mail pero pues la prueba en otras maquinas si cargan solo que en esa pc no, no se si tenga que ver con el mensaje que manda                                                                                                                                                                                   
 "se han bloqueado algunas imágenes para evitar que el remitente identifique su equipo"

Comment: Ok, eliminé mi respuesta porque a alguien no le gustó la votaron negativo, a pesar de que no le veo nada de malo. Intenta usar `<img src="file:///C:/Users/JORGE/Documents/Img/sol.jpg" alt="Mi Firma" />`, es todo lo que diré.

Comment: ya cambie la manera en la que inserto los imágenes solo me falta que funcione en la maquina

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Resolví el problema con la descarga de una pagina, edite sobre ella: filtre las lineas de código en inserción de imágenes y al final reemplace la imagen y la ubicación del archivo y cuando ejecute el archivo de html si me ejecuto la imagen y finalmente apareció.

Gracias por ayudarme con sus comentarios me ayudaron mucho

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: gracias bro buen dia.